# How to make the UI interractive to it's size?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

in this little addon i try to make an asset management system. 
I'd like that the **number of assets per row are adapting in real time to the size.x of the window** or maybe the other way around: the size of the icon are adapting. how is it possible to do that with python ?

any solution that's keeping the preview ratio 1:1 is really good.
but it may be trivial to do a more elaborated system.

[image]

```
import os
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name" : "Test [BD3D]",
    "author" : "BD3D",   
    "description" : "Wow such manager",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location" : "Operator",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}


class SCATTER_TestAddonPref(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    item_per_row : bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Items per rows",subtype='NONE',default=6,min=2,max=30)
    item_size    : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Items sizes",subtype='NONE',default=7,min=0,max=20)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        winx = bpy.context.window.x #could start doing something if window x was reactive. but it stay static. 
        item_per_row = round((winx-170)/150)

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text=str(winx))
        row.prop(self,"item_per_row") 
        row.prop(self,"item_size")       

        row = layout.row()
        row.alignment = 'LEFT'
        i=0
        for z in custom_icons:
            i+=1
            #row.separator(factor=1.0)
            row.box().template_icon(icon_value=custom_icons[z].icon_id,scale=self.item_size)
            row.separator(factor=1.0)
            if i == self.item_per_row:
                row = layout.row()
                row.alignment = 'LEFT'
                i=0
            #layout.label(text=str(i))


class Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname      = "TEST_PT_Panel" 
    bl_label       = "Scatter Icon test"
    bl_category    = "Scatter BETA"
    bl_space_type  = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_context     = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        global custom_icons

        layout.operator(SCATTER_OT_refresh_asset_manager.bl_idname, text="refresh", icon="FILE_REFRESH")

        # for z in custom_icons:
        #     layout.template_icon(icon_value=custom_icons[z].icon_id,scale=7)

#############################################################

class SCATTER_OT_size(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname      = "scatter.size"
    bl_label       = ""
    bl_description = "refresh the asset manager"

    def execute(self, context):
        print()
        return {'FINISHED'}



class SCATTER_OT_refresh_asset_manager(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname      = "scatter.refresh_asset_manager"
    bl_label       = ""
    bl_description = "refresh the asset manager"

    def execute(self, context):

        global custom_icons
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(custom_icons)
        custom_icons.clear()
        icon_set_up()

        return {'FINISHED'}

#############################################################


def icon_set_up():

    global custom_icons
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join

    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(preset_directory) if isfile(join(preset_directory, f))]
    custom_icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()

    for f in onlyfiles:
        if f[-4:] == ".jpg":
            custom_icons.load(f, os.path.join(preset_directory, f), 'IMAGE')




#################### INSERT BELOW r'folder_path'
#preset_directory = r'C:\Myfolder\myset_of_images\'
preset_directory = os.path.join(bpy.utils.user_resource('SCRIPTS'), "presets", "scatter_presets_custom\\")
custom_icons     = None

#############################################################

def register():

    icon_set_up()

    bpy.utils.register_class(Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SCATTER_OT_refresh_asset_manager)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SCATTER_TestAddonPref)


def unregister():

    global custom_icons                      #current removal method
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(custom_icons)  #corrent removal method
    custom_icons.clear()                     #corrent removal method

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCATTER_OT_refresh_asset_manager)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SCATTER_TestAddonPref)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Think you should be using [`grid_flow`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.grid_flow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
def draw(self, context):
    grid = self.layout.grid_flow()

    for icon in custom_icons:
        grid.template_icon(icon_value=icons.icon_id,scale=self.item_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

i just search in the api and it seems that there is multiples solution possible.
in this case the best code i found is grid_flow (thanks merlin for confirming)
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=grid_flow#bpy.types.UILayout.grid_flow

it also seems that ui_units_x and y are good contestors but i didn't try them yet.

```
class SCATTER_TestAddonPref(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    item_size    : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Items sizes",subtype='NONE',default=7,min=0,max=20)
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(self,"item_size")       

        row = layout.box().grid_flow(row_major=True, columns=0, even_columns=False, even_rows=False, align=False)
        row.alignment = 'LEFT'
        i=0
        for z in custom_icons:
            i+=1
            #row.separator(factor=1.0)
            prevbox= row.column(align=True)
            prevBOX=prevbox.box()
            prevBOX.template_icon(icon_value=custom_icons[z].icon_id,scale=self.item_size)
            prevBOX.label(text=z[:-4].replace("_"," ").title())
            prevbox.separator(factor=4)
```

Comment: There is no way to make these icons clickable?